# Calculator similar to Desmos but for $3$D

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, math-software, calculator

Is there a calculator with functionality similar to Desmos but in $3$ dimensions?  I am looking to learn about families of quadric surfaces so I am looking for a $3$D calculator with sliders.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slider_%28sandwich%29

Comment: Sounds good right about now.

Comment: Do you have a real graphing calculator?

Comment: If you do, let me know; there's an app which can do 3D graphing on the Ti-83 and 84

Comment: I have ti84 and 89

Comment: Interestingly enough, you can make (read: fake) 3D graphs in Desmos (which means you can use sliders) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nqom2ih05g
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/shw1wthey5

Comment: @JosiahKrutz thanks for sharing, now that's awesome!

Answer (score 41):

*Updated, December 2018*: I made the following website with the aim of producing a Desmos-like experience in 3D for my multivariable calculus students.

[math3d.org](https://www.math3d.org)

You can create and animate points, vectors, curves, surfaces (explicit & implicit), and vector fields. After creating a demonstration, you can save it and share.

Here are three scenes that I particularly like:

- [Parametric Curves, Velocity and Acceleration](https://www.math3d.org/motion)
- [Volumes of Revolution, Shell Method](https://www.math3d.org/horizontal_revolution_washer)
- [Hyperboloids as a Ruled Surface](https://www.math3d.org/ruled_hyperboloid) (+screenshot) [image]

This project is [on Github](https://github.com/ChristopherChudzicki/math3d-react). If you find bugs or have ideas for improvements, please [open an issue](https://github.com/ChristopherChudzicki/math3d-react/issues)!

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. I'm taking multivariable calculus this semester, discovered MathBox.js, and was wanting to make something like this, but haven't had time (lots of homework) to build anything this sophisticated. So, thanks!

Comment: This is awesome. Exactly what i want! I'm using it to visualize my example in textbook. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: @Ovi Glad you like it! See updated post.

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki Very nice! Just had time to check it out. One small thing though; when graphing an explicit surface, I tried to change the domain for $x, y$ and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hmm actually I figured it out; if you just change the domain, it doesn't update. But if you change the surface as well after you change the domain, then the domain updates as well.

Comment: @Ovi Thanks for letting me know. I fixed that, and added my contact informationm, since SO comments are probably not the best place to report bugs :)

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki Hello! Your calculator is soo good I just keep coming back to it haha. Unfortunately your link to it is not working for some reason.

Comment: @Ovi Thanks, fixed the link.

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki Thank you very much! :)

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Comment: Wow that is really cool, did you use something like WebGL to do those renderings?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai The graphics are powered by MathBox (https://github.com/unconed/mathbox) which is js library for interfacing with WebGL and ThreeJS.

Comment: thanks for making it public, a feature request: a sum feature is very useful, as in $\sum (\sin(nx)\sin(ny)/n^2,n,1,5)$

Comment: its great, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to attach an image for exact 3d positioning?

Comment: Your website is very smooth. Nice job. Now it is a part of my "always open" tabs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am having problems plotting cylinder. How can I plot it?

Comment: (+1)How was it programmed?

Answer (score 15):

GeoGebra does exactly what you want:

https://www.geogebra.org/3d

It already supports all quadrics. You can try it here:

https://www.geogebra.org/3d?command=a=1;z=x%5E2-a*y%5E2#3d

Comment: At times formula editor of Geogebra erases what you  typed partially or entirely and it is not clear what the error was. Better to type somewhere else and copy/paste on GG.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on a Mac, you can try the included application called Grapher:

1. Open Grapher by opening Spotlight (Command+Space) and typing 'Grapher' (and hitting enter)
2. Click '3D Graph' and hit the Choose button
3. Your text cursor should be to the right of 'z=' inside a text box; type any 3D function including the parameter 'a', such as sin(a*x), and hit enter
4. Click the plus button at the bottom left hand corner of the window, and click New Equation
5. Erase the 'z=', type 'a=2', and hit enter
6. Open the Equation menu and select Animate Parameter
7. Now drag the slider to change the parameter!
8. (optional) If you want to have the slider act continuously, click the right most 'Settings' button above the slider (with the two checkboxes and lines), and check the box labeled Continuous Range

Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

You can actually just use Desmos!

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/euncwbhqlb

Comment: Doesn't allow for rotation, or other nice features

Answer (score 2):

http://www.graphycalc.com/ is an excellent site. try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Just about all of the 3D plotters I've seen online fail in a few major areas:

1. Asymptotes. For example, $f(x,y) = \tan(x)$ shouldn't have vertical planes in its graph.
2. Plot boundaries. Functions with restricted domains, i.e. $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, should not have jagged triangles where the domain ends (in this case the unit circle on the $xy$ plane).
3. Discontinuities. Related to #1, but also applies to step functions and the like. Discontinuities should not be visible as an abrupt vertical plane.

Awhile ago I attempted to address these issues in [Koval's 3D Grapher](https://alankoval.com/3dgrapher/src/index.html). Now at the time I wasn't nearly as clever as I really needed to be, so it still struggles with some things (notably $f(x,y)=\tan(x)+\tan(y)$ and other "2D asymptotes"), but in general it does pretty well:

[image]

Also supports spherical and cylindrical coordinates and some 1D and 2D parameterized graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Many years after the question was asked, but Desmos has now released their own on-line 3D graphing calculator with some nice functionality.

https://www.desmos.com/3d

Answer (score 1):

You might try http://web.monroecc.edu/manila/webfiles/calcNSF/JavaCode/CalcPlot3D.htm.  It has sliders available under the Parameters->Adjust Parameters menu option.

Comment: link is dead, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This is nice too. Try it out https://www.geogebra.org/3d?lang=en  :)

Comment: In this case, the questioner asked for an online graphing calculator, so a link to the site is appropriate.  ^_^